# Flutter ScopedModel error " Only static members can be accessed in initializers"

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

I want to pass the ScopedModel to another page. Or in the initState call the ScopedModel so I can use the data.

```
  final MainModel model;
  IndexPage(this.model);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return IndexPageState();
  }
}

class IndexPageState extends State<IndexPage> {
  final pages = [
    HomePage(),
    CreatePage(),
    MapPage(widget.model),
  ];
```

When I do this I have this error:

Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martinez, you would need to move the declaration of your pages inside initState()

```
class IndexPageState extends State<IndexPage> {

List<Widget> pages;

@override
void initState() {  
   pages = [
        HomePage(),
        CreatePage(),
       MapPage(widget.model),
      ];
}
```

Comment: Exclude the word `final` or you are creating a local variable, rather than waiting to the instance variable.